# Что значит fn в коде - function(fn) { fn(data); }?

Tags: javascript, шаблоны-проектирования, observer

Пытаюсь разобраться в [этом](https://habr.com/ru/post/70793/) примере кода. А именно в следующем блоке

```js
Publisher.prototype.deliver = function(data) {
  this.subscribers.forEach(
    function(fn) {
      fn(data);
    }
  );
  return this;
};
```

Что такое fn в данном случае? Похоже на callback. Но какой именно если в функцию deliver передаётся только data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.subscribers = [];` - является массивом функций

```
var f = function print(data){
  console.log(data);
}
this.subscribers.push(f);
```

поэтом `forEach` перебирает все функции в `subscribers` и применяет их, `fn` - в данном конкретном случае является одной из функции в `subscribers` (так как идёт перебор всех элементов массива, `fn` является псевдонимом для текущего элемента массива).

```
this.subscribers.forEach(
  function(fn) { 
    fn(data);
  }
);
```

в моём случае `subscribers` содержит единственную функцию `print`, которая напечатает значение переменной `data`.

Comment: Понятно. Этот function() запутывает. Со стрелочной было бы так: fn => { fn(data) } ?

Comment: да, именно так.